# Bacula Director and Storage in LAN

Tags: linux, networking, security, bacula

I have two networks LAN and DMZ.. Machines in DMZ are accesible from internet ( only over http). In LAN I have servers that see all LAN and all DMZ machines but machinse from DMZ don't see any LAN servers. Machines in LAN have access only to all LAN and DMZ, no direct access to internet and no access from internet.

`DMZ <------ LAN` `DMZ ----X--->LAN`

I'm planning to configure Bacula as major backup system.

My plan is to install Bacula Director and Storage deamon on the same server in LAN for safety reasons.

So my question is:

Will this configuration work, is it posible for bacula director and storage deamon installed on server in LAN to makes backup servers that are in my DMZ?

Or in this network configuration Bacula should be in DMZ? (If yes will I can backup with it servers in LAN ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't install Bacula Storae Deamon in LAN. I checked by installing DIR and SD on the same machine on LAN (only for testing), installed FD on one of my machines in DMZ. DIR see them because comunication between them is like `dir--->fd`. After configuring backup and manualy running job from bconsol I'm getting error :

`Fatal error: Failed to connect to Storage daemon`

So DIR can be in LAN but SD must be visible for all FD clients so it must be installed in DMZ to.

Answer (score 1):

You can put Bacula Director and Bacula Storage Daemon on a server on DMZ. This server must access to tape driver or to backup storage media.

You can put multiple Bacula File Dameon on your DMZ and/or LAN server. In the bacula file daemon configuration  there isn't any ip address or hostname of the bacula director as you can see in the documentation http://www.bacula.org/manuals/en/install/install/Client_Fi_daemon_Configura.html

There is only a tcp connection from the bacula director to the bacula file daemon (tcp port 9102 for default), there aren't any tcp connection from File Daemon to Director Daemon. Obviously you need to install the file daemon in server mounting the filesystem that you want backup.